# Other use of profile photos: legality fair-use and permissions

Tags: copyright, gdpr, privacy

I'm building an app that works across mobile devices and browsers. There is a chat component and I will be showing the profile photos that I find on the user's phone book (not from the image folders). To make these images visible on the web if the user works on a browser, I upload the profile photos from the user's phone to a server, and deliver them to the web app.

To support OTHER users, if they do not have a profile photo on their phone, I intend to display the first one that was uploaded, which came from somebody else's phone.

The app asks for permission to use the users phone book. And there is fine print that the profile photos will be used in this manner.

Irrespective of the fine-print, is this 'acceptable use'? Am I opening my company to some risk?

Comment: I upvoted this question because I think it is an interesting question, but not to endorse this practice. I fully agree with Trish. It is a bad idea to publish images from the users device without explicit consent of the user, explicit consent of the person depicted and not even knowing what those images *actually* depict. And I don't think that any kind of fine print users probably never read makes it OK. Even if it were OK legally (which I doubt), it would  certainly not be ethically OK.

Comment: @Philipp That's precisely how we're supposed to use the upvote button. A good question is never limited to things that are personally, or generally, agreeable. We upvote for others to see the answer "DON'T DO THIS".

Comment: If you want "default" profile icons, I suggest copying [SE's approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278/136378) instead.

Comment: Which country do you live in? GDPR doesn’t apply outside the EU.

Comment: I live in India, where fine print sort of covers most abuse, and seeking legal remedies is often an exercise in futility (or death). Yet as this is an app with potentially global reach, I must obviously conform to the strictest legislation. Based on these informative comments I have changed the design to show only those avatars on a users phone to that user only.

Comment: @SunilGupta Even ignoring what is legal, you should also try to consider what is _right_. Informed consent is important; that's why more and more jurisdictions are enshrining it into law. It's not important _because_ it's in law!

Comment: If you don't plan to take payments from EU users, you shouldn't care what GDPR says: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81602/why-does-the-gdpr-matter-to-me-a-us-citizen-with-no-property-in-europe/81624#81624. But +1 to @wizzwizz4 - think whether or not its the *right* thing to do.

Comment: Even if you don't *take payments from* EU users, if you're mishandling PII of EU persons and your business has *any presence* in EU jurisdictions (or might decide to do so in the future), you may be in for a nasty surprise.

Comment: @Brian I've come to prefer initials as the default "image" (quite common in microsoft products).  They're clearly associated with a user (and taken from the name  that user has set so aren't additional PII).

Comment: @ChrisH - initially (on the web) the only thing I have is the phone number..., agreed that once I get the name from the phone, I could use the initials if there is no avatar - the issue is that the name too may be "private" so even that cannot be shared across users (as my original question was about sharing the avatar).

Comment: @SunilGupta if you don't have the name, you can't use it and need to use something anonymous.  But if you look at WhatsApp for example, at signup you give the name that's to be used in that app.  Their wording: "This name will be visible to your... contacts" - that gets you a name they're happy to share.  It sounds like you're trying to make it simple by grabbing their existing info, but even it was legal it wouldn't be appropriate.

Answer (score 50):

## BAD idea

It is one thing to upload the phonebook and associated pictures for use of the owner of the phonebook.

It isn't a fair use of the phonebook pictures - and you might not have a license anyway, as some people associate photos with numbers that they don't have a license to associate with anyway.

But what if instead of a photo of the person, the first photo someone associated with the person is a photo of something like... crack cocaine, a photo of someone in a very compromising situation, just genitals, or some other thing that is just as tasteless or possibly criminal to share? In that case, your company is possibly committing defamation, and in case sharing or possessing of the image itself is illegal, your company is now the actor and liable. Depending on the content of the picture, distribution of pornographic material (possibly even *underage* material of that sort) could be up that alley just as much as [hate speech through symbols](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79604/what-content-is-banned-in-germany-in-whatsapp-profile-pictures/79605#79605), usage of banned symbols ([such as swastikas in Gernamy](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78348/why-do-some-laws-make-saying-heil-hitler-illegal-when-other-laws-allow-freedom/78349#78349)) and many many others.

Comment: And it's sooo easy to abuse if you know how the system works.

Answer (score 19):

### Super illegal

Just focusing on the GDPR, what is your legitimate basis for taking the personal information of a third-party?

Comment: This is a teaching/student app. When a teacher/student adds a new contact (which can be via a telephone number, may not be in that user's phone book) - I wanted a way to show a profile picture. There are apps (like TrueCaller, which also have user consent) to show the phone users profile to others, when they call someone. Yes, these do not show profile photos from their phonebook... anyway, it's likely that my reasoning will not be a 'legitimate basis' under GDPR...

Comment: @SunilGupta the point is that a GDPR legitimate interest (LI) requires a balancing test. Here, the data subjects are (a) the person whose contact book you're uploading, and (b) the person described by that contact. You would have to balance their interests/rights/freedoms against your interest in providing default contact pics. There's a slim chance that you might have a LI if both parties can reasonably expect this, in particular if everyone involved is a user of your platform. But I strongly suspect that your interest does not outweigh those people, especially considering personality rights.

Comment: @SunilGupta and **especially** with what some people associate with people's numbers. Dick-pics are only the tip of the iceberg.